# How to fix Gnome Calculator missing +/- button?

Tags: 18.10, calculator, gnome-calculator

did someone faced really weird (and maybe funny) problem with gnome Calculator 3.30.1 on Ubuntu 18.10? It is missing [+/-] button in all modes so there is no way to use negative numbers...
Is there some way to fix it?

EDIT:

I found this screenshot of some old Calculator: with [+/-] button between [0] zero and [.] dot buttons

[image: calculator]

Comment: Providing a picture maybe helpful.  I can enter negative numbers using a - button, and using the keyboard.  `apt-cache policy` says my version is `Installed: 1:3.30.1-1ubuntu1` and I tried basic, advanced, financial, programming..

Comment: I see, yes it is possible to add minus sign before any other input and number is considered negative. However all the time there was button [+/-], the same as it is in every other calculator application or even "hardware" calculators to be able to change between + and - sign of number actually shown on display. Maybe this is some kind of weird and unwanted "new feature" :D

Comment: I also added a link to a picture found on net

Comment: If yours looks like the picture, it's different to what I see (which maybe is because of config/theme or tweaks; I've tweaked my DE).  eg. my basic mode can be seen with https://i.imgur.com/baodfid.png and advanced https://i.imgur.com/8fEWcRB.png - both rather different to your example (alt-prscn to upload window)

Comment: what I attached are images of old Calculator to see that [+/-] button was always there. My actual look is as on your image where is [+/-] button missing and that's my problem...

Comment: I don't know, but from what I can see this look was introduced in GNOME 3.24 as an improvement (design wise).  However if you need quick simple calculations & use gnome you can use search now too https://blogs.gnome.org/aday/files/2014/09/search-calculator.png (Ubuntu 17.10 & up)

Comment: I wonder if people who "improved" gnome calculator this way did ever use it since then... :-)